# Does 'as' act as preposition or adverb in following sentence?

Tags: grammar

"I deeply regret his sudden death, "state media quoted President as saying on behalf of the government and people.

Here in this sentence, does 'as' acts as a preposition or adverb???

I have another question.....

In the sentence, does 'saying' act as present participle after adverb 'as' or as gerund (i.e object of preposition 'as') after 'as'????

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll find "[quoted as saying](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quote%20as%20saying)" listed in the dictionary as an idiom in itself. In this idiom, "as" is acting as a *preposition*.

'Is' can be used to describe the purpose or quality of someone or something. (see [definition A1 in Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as))

In your example, the quotation is a description that is being attributed to someone as a quality they possess.

Comment: So, 'saying' acts as a object of preposition 'as' and it (saying) is gerund here??? Is it right??

Comment: I don't think it means 'like' here. "As" can also have a predicative use. Compare: *Sam was described as the richest person in America.* This indicates that "the richest person in America" is a description that has been applied to Sam.

Comment: I think "saying" would be a present participle, describing the person and what they're doing at that time.